# sendKeys(Key.ENTER) not working in selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Im trying to login into a page by pressing ENTER after writing down the username/pw.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="input-username"]')).sendKeys(caUsername);
driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="input-password"]')).sendKeys(oldpw);
driver.findElement(By.xpath('/html/body')).sendKeys(Key.ENTER);
```

However, it doesnt work and the console says

ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible

also, the chrome driver seems to do atleast something.
it enters the pw and username but then it seems to reload the page.

What to do?

Comment: I think you shouldn't use page body as locator for this purpose. Can you try `driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="input-password"]')).sendKeys(oldpw).sendKeys(Key.ENTER);`?

Comment: doesnt work, 'Invalid or unexpected token'

Comment: What if to replace `Key.ENTER` with `Keys.ENTER`?

Comment: Why are you not trying to use `WebElement#click()` method on login button element instead??

Comment: If your working on elements inside a form... then just use submit() method on any of the element. You can also use this method on the form element.

Comment: i set the variable as Key: const Key = webdriver.Key;

Comment: i want to use the enter key because in another form no other option works. the root problem is, that on this form i need to fill in 2 input of the type date. it works when i fill in the first by sending the keys of the current day in the format dd/mm/yyyy which works with getDate(), getMonth(). but when i jump over to the next input of the type date the first input turns white without any character in there. it ismply deletes the things i filled in. It is strange because when i do the same things the webdriver does on my browser, it works fine.

Comment: try once driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="input-password"]')).sendKeys(oldpw,Keys.TAB,Keys.ENTER);

Comment: this worked! still i got that problem with the date input. dont know if i should post it here more in detail

Comment: Did you try to use "submit()"; method?

driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="input-password"]')).submit();

Comment: it worked with the Key.ENTER at the end as a second key that is sent to the element.